# VBA: Create multiple pivot charts from multiple pivot tables in 1 sheet [Error: Method 'SetSourceData' of object '_chart' failed]

Tags: vba, excel

Firstly I created 4 pivot tables into 1 worksheet named OOTWeeklyTrendperPlatform, OOTWeeklyTrendperFailureMode, OverallWeeklyTrendperDereel, OverallWeeklyTrendperEngDataValue. These portion was completed successfully.

After that from each of these 4 **pivot tables** I wanted to create **pivot chart**. So there is 4 pivot tables and 4 pivot charts inside 1 worksheet.

My sequence of work is this way (table and chart name is for illustration purpose) table1 then chart1 then table2 then chart2 and so on. The problem is that after completed table1, chart1, and table2; I get an error when producing chart2 (or second chart correspond to table2). Please find shortened code below.

```
Sub MakePivotTableDereel()
    Dim PTCache As PivotCache, PTCache1 As PivotCache
    Dim PT As PivotTable, PT1 As PivotTable, PT2 As PivotTable, PT3 As PivotTable

    Dim rngChart As Range, rngChart1 As Range, rngChart2 As Range, rngChart3 As Range
    Dim objChart As ChartObject, objChart1 As ChartObject, objChart2 As ChartObject, objChart3 As ChartObject

    Dim PivotDereel As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Delete PivotSheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("PivotDereel").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

'   Create Pivot Cache
    Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)

'   Add PivotDereel sheet
    Set PivotDereel = Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotDereel"
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "OOT Weekly Trend per Platform"
    Cells(1, 1).Font.Size = 16
    Cells(1, 15).Value = "OOT Weekly Trend per Failure Mode"
    Cells(1, 15).Font.Size = 16
    Cells(1, 29).Value = "Overall Weekly Trend per Dereel"
    Cells(1, 29).Font.Size = 16
    Cells(1, 39).Value = "Overall Weekly Trend per Eng Data Value"
    Cells(1, 39).Font.Size = 16

'   Create pivot table OOTWeeklyTrendperPlatform
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=PivotDereel.Cells(4, 1), TableName:="OOTWeeklyTrendperPlatform")
    ' set table properties below
    With PT
        .PivotFields("Work Week").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("PLATFORM").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("EngDataValue").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("LotID").Orientation = xlDataField
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = False
        .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
        .PivotFields("Count of LotID").Caption = "Lot ID"
    End With
    ' Filter unwanted data below
    PT.PivotFields("EngDataValue").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With PT.PivotFields("EngDataValue")
        .PivotItems("BROKEN SEAL").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("DAMAGED MATERIAL").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("COGHOLE DAMAGE").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("DEBRIS IN TAPE").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("DRIFTED COVER TAPE").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("DROPPED REEL").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("EMPTY POCKET").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("ENGINEERING REQUEST").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("LOOSE COVER TAPE").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("MACHINE COUNT ERROR").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("MACHINE LOCKED UP").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("OUT OF MATERIALS").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("OUT OF PURGE TIME").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("OVER/UNDER SEALED").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("PART OUT OF POCKET").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("PO ERROR").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("TECH PURGED SYSTEM").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("THICK/THIN SEAL").Visible = False
    End With
    PT.PivotFields("EngDataValue").EnableMultiplePageItems = True

'   Create pivot chart OOTWeeklyTrendperPlatform
    Debug.Print PT.TableRange2.Columns.Count
    'Use the ChartObjects.Add Method to add an embedded Pivot Chart, which is represented as a ChartObject object. Note that the arguments Left and Width are mandatory to specify in this method. This method allows you to set the position and size (both in points) of the chart.
    Set objChart = Sheets("PivotDereel").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Top:=25 * (PT.TableRange2.Rows.Count), Width:=300, Height:=200)
    'set data source range for the Chart:
    Set rngChart = PT.TableRange2
    With objChart.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=rngChart
    End With

    With objChart.Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "OOT Weekly Trend per Platform"
        .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
        .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
    End With

'   Create pivot table OOTWeeklyTrendperFailureMode
    Set PT1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=PivotDereel.Cells(4, 15), TableName:="OOTWeeklyTrendperFailureMode")
    With PT1
        .PivotFields("Work Week").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Failure Mode").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("EngDataValue").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("LotID").Orientation = xlDataField
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = False
        .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
        .PivotFields("Count of LotID").Caption = "Lot ID"
    End With
    PT1.PivotFields("EngDataValue").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With PT1.PivotFields("EngDataValue")
        .PivotItems("BROKEN SEAL").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("DAMAGED MATERIAL").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("COGHOLE DAMAGE").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("DEBRIS IN TAPE").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("DRIFTED COVER TAPE").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("DROPPED REEL").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("EMPTY POCKET").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("ENGINEERING REQUEST").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("LOOSE COVER TAPE").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("MACHINE COUNT ERROR").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("MACHINE LOCKED UP").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("OUT OF MATERIALS").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("OUT OF PURGE TIME").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("OVER/UNDER SEALED").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("PART OUT OF POCKET").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("PO ERROR").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("TECH PURGED SYSTEM").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("THICK/THIN SEAL").Visible = False
    End With
    PT1.PivotFields("EngDataValue").EnableMultiplePageItems = True

'   Create pivot chart OOTWeeklyTrendperFailureMode

    'Use the ChartObjects.Add Method to add an embedded Pivot Chart, which is represented as a ChartObject object. Note that the arguments Left and Width are mandatory to specify in this method. This method allows you to set the position and size (both in points) of the chart.
    Set objChart1 = Sheets("PivotDereel").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Top:=25 * (PT1.TableRange2.Rows.Count), Width:=300, Height:=200)
    'set data source range for the Chart:
    Set rngChart1 = PT1.TableRange2

    With objChart1.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=rngChart1
    End With

    With objChart.Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "OOT Weekly Trend per Platform"
        .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
        .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
    End With
'below is the portion to create 3rd and 4th pivot tables and charts
end sub
```

***I get error: Method 'SetSourceData' of object '_chart' failed*** at part,

```
With objChart1.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=rngChart1
        End With
```

This part suppose to assign source data for the second chart. But it fails. Do you have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If any cell in a pivot table is selected, a chart that you insert will automatically use the whole pivot table as its source data. I just ran this on a worksheet with a handful of pivot tables:

```
for i=1 to 4
  activesheet.pivottables(i).tablerange2.cells(1,1).select
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
  ' here you need to specify chart type and style, size and position, etc.
next
```

No need for SetSourceData (which gave me unexpected problems before I simplified as above).

Comment: Haven't tried your solution yet since I am outside now. But I am curious about AddChart2 332 part. What does 332 refer to?

Comment: 322 is the chart type.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is there an error message? Does something look wrong?

Comment: I just discovered that AddChart2 was new in Excel 2013, and the specific style 332 might also be new to this version. I'll update my code.